# Rails 3.2.13 routes: optional parameter constraints an the begin of the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, constraints, optional-parameters

I`m trying to put my routes to better use with optional params and constraints! But it does not seem to work!

### Goal

My goal is to make the following path work
`(/:section_id)/:post_type_id(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))`
so that posts could be rendered with or without section.

### Working solution

Temporary solution i got is to make duplicate routes like so:

```
section_constraints = lambda { |request| 
  Section.exists?(id: request.params[:section_id])
}
post_type_constraints = lambda { |request|
  PostType.exists?(id: request.params[:post_type_id])
}

scope ':section_id',:as=>'section', :constraints => section_constraints do
  root :to=>'posts#index'
  scope ':post_type_id',:as=>'post_type', :constraints => post_type_constraints do
    get '(/:year(/:month(/:day)))' => 'posts#index', :as=> :posts
    get '(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))' => 'posts#show', :as => :post
  end
end

scope ':post_type_id',:as=>'post_type', :constraints => post_type_constraints do
  get '(/:year(/:month(/:day)))' => 'posts#index', :as=> :posts
  get '(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))' => 'posts#show', :as => :post
end
```

so i get routes like this:

```
/:section_id/:post_type_id(/:year(/:month(/:day)))
/:section_id/:post_type_id(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))
```

and

```
/:post_type_id(/:year(/:month(/:day)))
/:post_type_id(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))
```

routes like `/first_section_id/news` and /first_section_id and all others down the routes file work fine.

BUT

### To cut off duplication

I would like to make a constraint on an optional param! It should look like so:

```
scope '(/:section_id)', constraints: section_constraints  do
  scope '/:post_type_id', constraints: post_type_constraints do
    get '(/:year(/:month(/:day)))' => 'posts#index', :as=> :posts
    get '(/:year(/:month(/:day(/:id))))' => 'posts#show', :as => :post
  end
end
```

but this way it does not recognize paths without section at all! What do you think guys? which way should i look to make my routes nice and clean?